# How do you get an Observable of a Event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs

I'm wondering how do you get an Observable of a Event in Angular 2?

For example I want to subscribe to a click event but only emit after two clicks? Is possible to get a Observable of `MouseClick` event objects?

Say if I wanted to filter by `button` or `ctrlKey` - Or a Observable of `KeyboardEvent` and filter by `key` \ `keyCode` - Or any possible future scenario

I have read http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html but the `valueChanges` property is `Observable<string>`

I have also seen on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5489 that it is possible to do something like:

```
this.clickStream = new Subject();
...
<button (click)="clickStream.next($event)">Click Me</button>
```

Is the `Subject` method above the correct way to do it? I am unsure.

I don't have much experience with Angular 2 or RxJS, but I am interested by both and am investigating them with the idea of using them in future projects

**Edit**

Here's my Plunker with a simple click use case http://plnkr.co/edit/u1A7ve2fAYigjwaZ0x1v?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable has a [fromEvent operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md), but to use it you'll need a reference to the native element. The way to get it is to use viewChild/contentChild to get an elementRef.

Next you can bind to its click like so:

```
var clickStream = Observable.fromEvent(btnRef.nativeElement, 'click');
```

If I understood the filtering thing properly, you want the stream to emit only after the click was pressed twice, or to be more precise, once for each 2 clicks, to do so, use the [bufferWithCount operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/bufferwithcount.md):

```
var triggerFor2Clicks = clickStream.bufferWithCount(2);
```

This will emit an array of 2 events at a time, so your action handler can be:

```
triggerFor2Clicks.subscribe(() => my2ClicksHandler);
```

Note that the arguments are empty, notated as '()' since you don't really care for the events, just to the fact that they were 2 of them.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! The two clicks thing was a example a colleague asked me of how to change the logic. I was really wondering if it is possible to get a Observable of MouseClick event objects, say if I wanted to filter by `button` or `ctrlKey` - Or a Observable of `KeyboardEvent` and filter by `key` \ `keyCode`

Comment: I have also just seen a USE WITH CAUTION on the Angular 2 API ref for `ElementRef` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html

Comment: An example of filtering (left mouse down only):
Observable.fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousedown').filter((md:MouseEvent) => md.which == 1)

As for the warning, you are correct, but still, it works :-)

Comment: Do you think you could help me make a small demo of this?
I am trying to edit the Angular 2 example on Plunker but I get the exception 'bufferWithCount is not a function', I must be importing something wrong http://plnkr.co/edit/u1A7ve2fAYigjwaZ0x1v?p=preview

Comment: hmm, Is `.bufferWithCount()` in the latest version 5 of RxJS?
I just changed my Plunker example to use version 4 and the exception is no longer being thrown http://plnkr.co/edit/u1A7ve2fAYigjwaZ0x1v?p=preview

Comment: Yes it is. See this page for migration guide:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md .

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful! I'll update my Question with the Plunker