# How can I use an observer to simulate an event?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I initially used `let foo = Subject<void>` to simulate an event. I created a subject and simply called it `foo.next()`. Every subscriber received the message, all good.

Today I learned that this technique works, but isn't meant to be used. As [this article](https://benlesh.medium.com/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93) outlines, this is a misunderstanding made by beginners... raises hand...guilty.

Bottom line is, "it’s not really the “Rx way”". So instead I looked at `Observable`. Given is the simple code example below:

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  observer.next(3);
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next(4);
    observer.complete();
  }, 1000);
});

console.log('just before subscribe');
observable.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
});
console.log('just after subscribe');
```

This example above is straight forward, but I don't understand how I can use this to simulate an event. I only see the observer used inside the scope that sends `1`, `2`, ... around.

How would I connect this to e.g. a button or click event? Am I supposed to use the passed `observer` instance outside the observable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get an Observable of a Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743744/how-do-you-get-an-observable-of-a-event)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Unfortunately I am looking into a more general explanation how an Observable works. A Subject works exactly how I assumed it works. An `Observable` which is actually nothing else works very different and I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an `Observable` from a DOM Event, you should use the [`fromEvent`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent) operator which takes as first parameter a reference to a DOM node, and an event name as second parameter.

Example of usage:

```
const element = document.getElementById(...); // Or any other code that returns a DOM node

const obs = fromEvent(element, 'click');
```

Comment: Thanks! I have already seen `fromEvent` and my question resulted indeed around that topic. But my goal was to generally understand the use or behaviour of Observables. A `Subject` works exactly how I assumed it would work. An `Observable` on the other hand doesn't (although they are both related).

Comment: An observable is not different of a subject, it's just the subscribable part of it. Generally you should not attempt to create subjects but retrieve observables from the framework and libraries you are using, or rxjs operators like fromEvent